# javascript: sum content of an object based on another parameter in the object and display in a new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

I have the following object / array:

```js
activities = [
    { Date: "2019-01-05 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 20},
    { Date: "2020-03-15 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 5},
    { Date: "2019-06-23 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 50},
    { Date: "2020-05-21 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 7},
    { Date: "2019-11-02 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 6}
];
```

and I would like to create a new array which sums up distance based on the year, like this:

```js
activitiesPerYear = [
    { Date: 2019, Sport: "Running", Distance: 76},
    { Date: 2020, Sport: "Running", Distance: 12},
];
```

Please find below my code.
I have succeeded in extracting the year from the date value and turn it into an array.
I have managed to sum all the distances but not been able to do it based on the year component.
Thanks for you help. I'm new to coding in javascript.

```js
activities = [
    { Date: "2019-01-05 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 20},
    { Date: "2020-03-15 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 5},
    { Date: "2019-06-23 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 50},
    { Date: "2020-05-21 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 7},
    { Date: "2019-11-02 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 6}
];

var activitiesPerYear = activities.map(a => [new Date(a.Date).getFullYear(), a.Sport, +a.Distance]);
console.log(activitiesPerYear);

var sum = activitiesPerYear.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur[2];
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: This is _much_ easier done if you start with a second, empty object and fill that as `{ "2019": [{sport:..., distance: ...}, {sport:..., distance: ...], ...}], "2020": [ {...}, {...}, ...]}` by running through your array, rather than reducing one to the other.

Comment: Welcome!
Why not take first four characters from `Date`?
Could the `Sport` be anything other than `"Running"`, if not but will have `Distance`, do you care, if not, is `{year:sum, year2:sum2,...}` acceptable, if not, do you want by `year+sport`?

Answer (score 0):

We need to reduce the object into an object whose value we will keep on increasing on the basis of the current object.

Below given is the very basic and straight forward approach.

```js
activities = [
    { Date: "2019-01-05 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 20},
    { Date: "2020-03-15 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 5},
    { Date: "2019-06-23 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 50},
    { Date: "2020-05-21 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 7},
    { Date: "2019-11-02 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 6}
];

var activitiesPerYear = activities.reduce((acc, record) => {
    var year = new Date(record.Date).getFullYear();

    if (!acc[year]) acc[year] = { Date: year, Sport: record.Sport, Distance: 0 };
    
    acc[year].Distance += record.Distance;

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(activitiesPerYear));
```

**Note:** There is one issue that currently if the same year has multiple values of `Sport` the above code will pick up the first value.
You can apply some business logic to aggregate it's value as well.

Comment: Your previous version was better: `{year:sum, year2:sum2,...}`...

Comment: Yeah, but I realized OP wanted something different in output. That's why decided to update it.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm not sure OP knows what they want.
What about type of sport?
What if is not measured by distance?
Why do they want an Array?
:)
I've asked them...  awaiting reply...

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that thought that's why I tried to mention the same at the end of the answer as well. Thanks for pointing it out for the OP in question's comment section. :)

Comment: thank you ! i'm not sure i understand your note about the multiple values of 'Sport'

Comment: ok i understand. Yes type of sport can change to other values. Therefore the sum will have to be by year and per type of sport. But i didn't mention it because i knew how to pre-sort the table activities for one specific activity before getting the sum of the distances.

Comment: @E102, `Sport:"Running"`, `Sport:"Ski-Walking"`, `Sport:"Crawling-Backwards"`, `Sport:"Weight-Lifting"`....

Comment: @E102, ok, if all records have date, sport, and either summabe or min/max, you can split them to an object/array in one shot, sorting included.

Comment: @E102 in that case the above solution might not be the most optimized code as you haven't given us the whole use case. I hope you will just take the understanding of `Array.reduce` from the above answer and form your own solution. Please read the @iAmOren's comment as well.

Comment: @E102, why is distance summable?  do you have some sport such as push-up which you also want to sum?  are all of them summable?
Are any of them record based: fasted/least time to run a kilometer, maximum weight lifted?
If not all summable, you can manipulate the data to include `type` that the `reduce` can work with.

Comment: yes thank you all. I have enough information between all of your comments and it helped me understand the concept of array.reduce which i was struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **array reduce** method to calculate the sum. After that make you required object array.

```js
activities = [
  { Date: "2019-01-05 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 20 },
  { Date: "2020-03-15 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 5 },
  { Date: "2019-06-23 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 50 },
  { Date: "2020-05-21 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 7 },
  { Date: "2019-11-02 00:00:00.000000", Sport: "Running", Distance: 6 },
];

var activitiesPerYear = activities.map((a) => [
  new Date(a.Date).getFullYear(),
  a.Sport,
  +a.Distance,
]);

var sum = activitiesPerYear.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
  if (!prev[cur[0]])
    prev[cur[0]] = { Date: cur[0], Sport: cur[1], Distance: cur[2] };
  else
    prev[cur[0]] = {
      Date: cur[0],
      Sport: cur[1],
      Distance: prev[cur[0]].Distance + cur[2],
    };
  return prev;
}, {});
sum = Object.values(sum);
console.log(sum);
```